# Passing local variables to partials

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm displaying a collection of post with a form to 'Like' a post in each of them. Also I'm using the same action inside the post page.

My code works with format.html but  with Ajax I got an error:

> NameError (undefined local variable or method `micropost' ....microposts/_like_grid.html.erb:2

I guess it works in pure HTML due to the :params I got when redirect_to the original page.

I've read many S.O. answer but I'm still really confused about how to passing variables to partials. In a post page Its easy for me to understand, because a get a single object from :params but I get confused when I need to do it in a collection. How iteration works on every partial rendered.

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user

  def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    current_user.like!(@micropost, current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end

  ...
```

users/show.html.erb:

```
<%= render @microposts %>
<%= will_paginate @microposts %>
```

The view: _micropost.html.erb

```
      <div id="like_form">
      <% if current_user.liking?(micropost) %>
        <%= render partial: 'microposts/unlike_grid', locals: { micropost: micropost } %>
      <% else %>
        <%= render partial: 'microposts/like_grid', locals: { micropost: micropost } %>
      <% end %> 
      </div>
```

_like_grid.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.likes.build, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :micropost_id, micropost.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Like" %>
<% end %>
```

like/create.js.erb:

```
$("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('microposts/unlike_grid')) %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just missed `micropost` when rendering in your `like/create.js.erb`

To fix it, pass `micropost` when rendering partials:

```
$("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('microposts/unlike_grid', locals: {micropost: @your_micropost})) %>");
```

Btw, you may find `@your_micropost` in your controller first

Comment: I still have the same problem:NameError (undefined local variable or method `micropost' in app/views/microposts/_unlike_grid.html.erb The problem seems to be inside _unlike_grid.html.erb not in .js.erb

Answer (score 0):

You are already setting up instance variable `@microsoft` in the `action`. You just need to pass that to you required partial. And you don't need to give `locals:` key variable when not using `partial:` key variable.

```
 $("#like_form").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('microposts/unlike_grid', micropost: @micropost)) %>");
```

Comment: Same problem: The problem seems to be inside _unlike_grid.html.erb not in .js.erb maybe my @micropost variable in controller is wrong?